# What is the impact of Universal analytics deprecation on Magento 2

Tags: magento2, magento2.4, magento2.4.2, google-analytics

To send ecommerce data from Magento 2 to analytics, we have out of the box configuration in admin Magento 2. In which we are adding universal tracking ID (UA-XXXXXXX-1), then its starts sending ecommerce data from Magento 2 website to Analytics.

But now in the Analytics dashboard we are seeing that Universal Analytics will stop processing data starting July 1, 2023. In this case how we will send ecommerce data to analytics. Is there any configuration changes we need to do from Magento 2 side?

What is the impact of this on Magento 2 configuration.

I need to understand going forward how we are sending ecommerce data from Magento 2 to analytics.

Thanks!